# select dropdown triggers mouseout on jQuery hover() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a slide in form with jQuery but if I open a select drop-down the form slides out or it starts to loop in and out.

here is my html:

```
<div id="hoverForm">
  <div id="label">
  </div>
  <div id="hoverForminner">
    <form>
    <!-- lots of form stuff -->
      <select class="dropdowdn" id="dropdowdn">
        <option selected="selected" value="">- Choose -</option>
        <option value="1">- One -</option>
        <option value="2">- Two -</option>
      </select>
    <!-- more form stuff -->
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $('#hoverForm').hover(
    function(){
      $('#hoverForminner').animate({marginLeft: '0'}, 200);
    },
    function(){
      $('#hoverForminner').animate({marginLeft: '-822px'}, 200);
    }
  );
});
```

How can I avoid that the mouse out if I open the select?

Comment: What effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: a left to right slide in if mouse is over the hoverForm div and the oposite if mouse leaves. Sorry I tought its clear from the animate(). The hoverForm is a fixed on left:0 and top:90px and the label div has a background image and its 45px wide and 60px high.

Comment: On here: http://jsfiddle.net/YNJzF/ the behavior is as expected. When the user clicks on an option of the dropdown, the mouse cursor finds itself outside `hoverForm` thus activating the animation to close it.

Comment: Ok, but the question still stands how to aviod this. How to include the the select's options? because I tried `$('#hoverForm, #hoverForm select option').mouseenter(function(){//do something}); $('#hoverForm').mouseleave(function(){//do something else});` but it has the same effect

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the issue entirely by forcing the size of `hoverForm` to be bigger than the dropdown and its options. That way, even after the user clicks on an option, the mouse cursor still finds itself on the element and not triggering the animation.

See http://jsfiddle.net/YNJzF/1/

For example, you can use the `padding` or `height` properties:

```
#hoverForm  {background:green; padding:90px 30px}​
```

You can also use jQuery to dynamically change the height based on the number of options:

```
$('#hoverForm').css('height',(originalHeight + $('.dropdowdn option').length*20)+'px')
```

Comment: I have height for hoverForm and hoverForminner and for the inner overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden; to make it compatibe with low resolution. And even if I add height it triggers the mouse leave. I was playing around with :focus selector but with my version with focus now hoverForm wont close until you click into another element because it stays in focus until than. on the hover callback i did this `if($('.dropdowdn').is(':focus')){ //do nothing }else{$('#hoverForminner').animate({marginLeft: '-822px'}, 200);}`